# What is the difference between `ls` and `l`?

Tags: linux, command-line, ubuntu, ls, alias

I accidentally typed `l` instead of `ls` today and found that the command still printed a list of the files in my current directory. Trying `l --help` brings up the help file for `ls` suggesting that `l` is just an alias of `ls`.

However, each file was suffixed by a `*`. Why is this and what does it mean?

In case it makes a difference, this is when running the latest stable version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I came here after seeing the tweet, Unix commands turned into companies , https://twitter.com/valaafshar/status/540694808382431232 and 'l' doesn't work on my mac! lol

Comment: @don_crissti the other one is broader, since it names about one more alias, and asks about more.

Comment: @muru The other answer does not explain what the `*` in front of each file is.

Comment: @BinaryZebra Considering the accepted answer here doesn't explain it either, I'm inclined to think it's a minor point. :shrug:

Comment: Use `type l` to find what is `l` (if anything), the try `alias l` to see what is the alias of `l`.

Comment: `l` was created so that you get (almost) the same output as `ls` when you are typing so fast and miss the last `s` :P

Answer (score 111, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:** understand what exactly this alias does, you can check out the `~/.bashrc` file and search for the term "`alias l=`". It is nothing but `ls -CF`

**LONG ANSWER**
A good way to inspect what a command is:

```
type l
```

If it's a program or a script, it will give you its location, if it is an alias, it will tell you what it's aliased to, if it's a function, it will print the funciton; otherwise, it will tell you if it is a built-in or a keyword.

Examples:

```
$ type l
l is aliased to `ls -CF'
$ type find
find is /usr/bin/find
$ type connecthome
connecthome is hashed (/usr/local/bin/connecthome)
$ type grep
grep is aliased to `grep --color=auto --binary-files=without-match --devices=skip'
$ type hello_se
hello_se is a function
hello_se () 
{ 
  echo 'Hello, Stack Exchangers!'
}
$ type type
type is a shell builtin
$ type for
for is a shell keyword
$ type nosuchthing
-bash: type: nosuchthing: not found
```

Comment: Now *that's* a cool trick. I'll have to remember that one.

Comment: This command (A bash builtin) is very useful. I'm amazed that I've never seen it mentioned everywhere.

Comment: Excellent examples, I think you covered it thoroughly.  Since I've seen people use `type` to check if a command is installed, I'll just mention here that it's possible for the hashed commands to be out of date, in which case `type <binary-name>` will return success for some time after `<binary-name>` has actually been deleted.

Answer (score 9):

```
$ l --help
l: command not found
```

Looks like you have an alias set up in your environment. Perhaps you have inherited a `.profile`, `.bashrc` or similar containing something like `alias l='ls -F'`.

```
-F, --classify
              append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
```

Try `which l` and `alias` to track down its definition.

Comment: specifically the `*` after a file name means that the file is executable

Answer (score 5):

FIXED: `l` is an `alias` for `ls -CF` ( I am not really sure ) in the default `.bashrc` in ubuntu

You can just type `alias` to check out all the aliases. It would be mentioned there.

Comment: `ls -d` that seems like the most useless alias ever. all that prints is `.`

Comment: -1: in Ubuntu 10.10 it's disabled (commented) by default, and it aliases to `ls -CF`.

Comment: but it was there in previous versions. and yes, it was ls -CF, i just didn't have access to an older ubuntu machine to test it out.

Answer (score 3):

I redefined all my `ls` shortcuts in my `.zshrc`.

This is the relevant section:

```
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ "$TERM" != "dumb" ]; then
    if [ -n ~/.dir_colors ]; then
        eval "`dircolors -b ~/.dir_colors`"
    else
        eval "`dircolors -b /etc/DIR_COLORS`"
    fi
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='ls --color=auto --format=vertical'
    #alias vdir='ls --color=auto --format=long'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias l='ls -CF'
alias ll='ls -ClhF'
alias la='ls -CaF'
alias lla='ls -CalhF'
alias l.='ls -CAF --ignore=\*'
alias ll.='ls -CAlhF --ignore=\*'
alias t='tree -C'
```

Note that `ls` is redefined itself:

```
% type ls
ls is an alias for ls --color=auto
```

Comment: You may like exa https://the.exa.website/ alias l='exa --long'

Comment: @johndpope yeah, coming back to this after so many years, I did use exa (and now eza) every now and then, but only on my machines. Anything that isn't mine, I still just use `ls` with a bunch of aliases... ¦D

Comment: created this the other day - wired to "lls" - good for me to visually highlight git repos that I've recently cloned https://chat.openai.com/share/654db02c-3a52-4056-9cde-d3f969b0802e

Answer (score 2):

By default, it is an alias for `ls -CF` in ubuntu.